# Cannot get multiple peer connections working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, webrtc

I am building a WebRTC framework that has many broadcasting entities that speak the WebRTC language, and a single web based client that displays multiple streams.

When I use a single peer connection in my client for one stream, I can display the video without any problem. When I add a second peer connection, the second video fails to play without any error indicating why.

If I do all the SDP and ICE signalling for connection 1, then all for connection 2, I find that connection 1's video will always play as soon as it is attached to the video element. Connection 2 however does not display anything when connected.

If I do the signalling for connection 1, then connection 2, then CLOSE  connection 1's peer connection (via pc.close()), then when I try to attach connection 2 to the video element then the video plays.

It seems they will not both stream at the same time no matter what I do.

For my testing, I am doing everything locally. All producing entities are on the same machine as the web client. Is this possibly an issue? I have a feeling that maybe both connections are trying to use the same ICE candidate connection? I'm not sure if that even make sense.

Has anyone else encountered similar issues?

Comment: What specific [tag:webrtc] implementation are you talking about? Chrome/Firefox/…? Some native library?

Comment: My test used firefox. I just tested on chrome and it actually works there. Any idea why firefox might have issues? Is this related to any other issues out there?